# When to use "guardarci" vs "guardare"

Tags: word-usage, pronouns, particles

I've been noticing several uses of guardarci as a demonstrative pronoun:

- *Guardarci il cielo*
- *Guardarci i film* (The full sentence is *[Tanto non potrei più guardarci i film](https://it.glosbe.com/it/en/guardarci)*)
- *Stavo per avvicinarmi e guardarci dentro, ma ho ricevuto un messaggio*

Is there a reason or a rule to not use "guardare" in these cases?

Comment: The first two, as they are, don't sound quite Italian, unless one constructs some ad hoc context in such a way that *-ci* makes sense (*Ho costruito un telescopio per guardarci il cielo* etc.). Where did you find them?

Comment: I think the sentences you are suggesting refers to "ci" as  the pronuoun "us". *Andiamo a guardarci il cielo o a guardarci un film*, let's go and watch the sky or a movie. That would be an informal , probably dialectal use of the expression. *Andiamo a guardare il cielo o un film*  would be the correct form.

Comment: @Josh61: I think this "ci" cannot refer to the pronoun "us". For instance, if in "guardarci il cielo" the "ci" particle would be interpreted as "us", we would be watching us instead of looking at the sky.

Comment: @Charo - Mi sto riferendo alle frasi proposte nella domanda. 'Guardarci un firm' si usa anche se non e' corretto, e significa 'guardare assieme un film'. Frasi come 'Andiamo a farci un giro, a berci un aperitivo, etc ' sono spesso  usate.

Comment: @Josh61's interpretation is interesting; especially in the spoken language, it is frequent to say things such as *mi mangio una bella bistecca*, *che ci vediamo stasera?* and so on. It is almost some kind of a [middle diathesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(grammar)#Middle). Unfortunately, in nachocab's examples the context is missing.

Comment: I guess that he heard those expressions rather than read them.

Comment: @Josh61: I think you can be true (and it's quite plausible for "guardarci un film"), but the interpretation of DaG is also possible. As DaG has stated, it would depend on the context.

Comment: @Charo - I have no problem with DaG answer, but my gut feeling is that those sentences are taken from live colloquial speech.

Comment: @Josh61: Yes, it may be that way.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've added the context for the second sentence (I couldn't find a link for the first one). They were both extracted from written examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *-ci* particle just means “with it”, “in it” and the like. (It is not to be confused with the homonymous *-ci* meaning “to us”, as in *Devi darci una risposta*, “You have to give us an answer”).

In a sentence like *Stavo per guardarci dentro*, you are saying “I was about to look in it”. You might well say *Stavo per guardare dentro*, just like in English you might say something like “I was about to look inside”: in both cases you are not explicitly specifying *dentro*, or “inside” what, but often it will be clear from the context.

Analogously, if you have a sentence like *Ho costruito un telescopio per guardarci il cielo* (“I built a telescope to look at the sky with”), you might modify it in *Ho costruito un telescopio per guardare il cielo* (“I built a telescope to look at the sky”).

Notice that this *-ci* (just like the *-ci* meaning “to us”) can also be used by itself, rather than as a suffix: *Ci guardo dentro* (“I look in it”).

Answer (score 3):

> Guardarci le stelle / i film =~ "The act of looking at the stars / watching "the" movies *for ourself*" **or** "The act of looking at the stars / watching "the" movies *in there*"

Apologizes for the "for ourself" part, which is hard to translate (at least for me), but I think I've got pretty close with it: expanding its meaning a bit, "for ourself" should be intended as "in a way so that the purpose of the whole thing is just for us to enjoy it". Again, still not quite there, but to understand this meaning thoroughly try to consider also, e.g., "Mi mangio una mela" compared to "Mangio una mela".

I second Josh61 in stating that the first acceptation is probably dialectical; *However that doesn't make it incorrect, it's perfect italian*. It's just that, in my experience, I've never heard of it, e.g., being used in Tuscany but I've heard of it, e.g., being used in Puglia.

In any case, as remarked in the comments by DaG already, the first two probably miss a context regardless; in that case, the "-ci" particle *could* mean "for ourself" as much as it could mean "in there" ("in there" in the same way it does in the third one). As you may know the "-ci" particle is very tricky in italian and its meaning can vary within a wide range depending on the actual context; therefore adding some context to both we could make four correct sentences out of them, two with "-ci" actually meaning "for ourself" and two with "-ci" actually meaning "in there":

> Andiamo a guardarci le stelle?
>   Andiamo a guardarci i film?
>   Cosa sei andato a fare nel giardino? - Sono andato a guardarci le stelle
>   Cosa sei andato a fare nella sala proiezioni? - Sono andato a guardarci i film

Answering the question itself: "Andiamo a guardarci le stelle / i film?" and "Cosa sei andato a fare nel giardino / nella sala proiezioni? - Sono andato a guardarci le stelle / i film" *could* be substituted with "Andiamo a guardare le stelle / i film?" and "Cosa sei andato a fare nel giardino / nella sala proiezioni? - Sono andato a guardare le stelle / i film" leaving the phrases grammatical, but in both cases part of the meaning would be lost (in the first case due to the reasons explained above and in the second case due to a missing implicit remark of "in there");

"Stavo per avvicinarmi e guardarci dentro, ma ho ricevuto un messaggio" *could* be substituted with "Stavo per avvicinarmi e guardare dentro, ma ho ricevuto un messaggio" as well but again, part of the meaning would be lost (again, due to a missing implicit remark of "in there")

Comment: "Sono andato in giardino a guardarci il cielo" mi suona male. Diresti una frase così?

Comment: @Josh61 No, perché in una frase che inizia con "Sono andato in giardino" "in giardino" è già esplicito fin dall'inizio, ma se dovessi rispondere ad una domanda "Cosa sei andato a fare nel giardino?" credo che potrei benissimo rispondere "Sono andato a guardarci le stelle", non è ridondante come "Sono andato in giardino a guardarci le stelle"

Comment: @Josh61: A me non sembra strano: in catalano si dice ["mirar-hi"](http://lletra.uoc.edu/especials/folch/monserda.htm). In questa poesia si va a una fontana per guardarci le foglie (ma potrebbe essere anche un giardino e si potrebbe guardare il cielo).

Comment: A pensarci bene, forse l'esempio della fontana sia meglio di quello del giardino perché le foglie si guardano veramente nella fontana, cioè l'acqua riflette l'immagine delle foglie. In questo senso, mi sa che l'esempio del telescopio di @DaG è più adatto o magari si potrebbe dire qualcosa come "si può usare un specchio per guardarci il cielo".

Answer (score 2):

1) They three phrases are all in perfect Italian and perfect Tuscan. I was born in San Miniato - between Pisa and Florence, from a Tuscan father and mother and I had four Tuscan grandparents.
2) "Guardarci i film" (considering the full sentence) could not mean "let's go and watch a movie" (movies, more precisely). That "ci" could only mean "in it" (say, a room) or "with it" (say, a projector) and not "for us" or "ourselves" or similar.
3) In the third case, "guardarci dentro" can only be "in it".
4) Only in the first phrase, the "ci" can relate to "us". In that case it reinforces the idea of "on our own", "alone", "for our pleasure", etc.