# "Ce" in "ce l'hai": what is its function?

Tags: grammar, particles

> Se tu non ce l'hai, allora dov'è la borsa?

I totally lost the function of "ce" in this sentence. Any input would be helpful.

Comment: See also the question «[When to use “guardarci” vs “guardare”](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/when-to-use-guardarci-vs-guardare)».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Ce" is the form that the "ci" particle assumes when put in front of "lo", "la", "li", "le", or "ne":

> ce<sup>1</sup> pron. e avv. – Forma che il pron. o avv. atono *ci* assume davanti a *lo*, *la*, *li*, *le*, *ne*; per es.: *ce lo disse*, *ce le diede*, *ce ne vollero*; anche in posizione enclitica: *spiegàrceli*, *pàrlacene*.

([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ce1/))

Speaking of "ci" itself, "ci" in this case is known as "ci attualizzante":

> [...] Nel parlato e nello scritto informale è molto diffuso l’uso di *ci* per rafforzare il verbo *avere* (il cosiddetto *ci attualizzante*) [...]
> In alcuni casi, l’uso di *ci* è obbligatorio [...]

([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ci_(La_grammatica_italiana)/))

Giving up finding a translation of "ci attualizzante" which could convey the exact meaning the expression has in Italian, the concept is that putting "ci" in front of "avere" strengthens the meaning of the verb:

> C(i) ho caldo
>
> C(i) hai sonno?
>
> C(i) avevamo fame

([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ci_(La_grammatica_italiana)/))

But in an handful of cases, such as this one, "ci" / "ce" is straight mandatory:

> «ce l’hai l’ombrello?» «ce l’ho» (non l’ho)

([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ci_(La_grammatica_italiana)/))

(as Fabio F. remarks, differently from what Treccani seems to state, in "non l'ho" "ce" is mandatory as well, and the phrase should rather be "non ce l'ho")

Which, in the end, narrows down the reasons behind the use of "ce" in "Se tu non ce l'hai, allora dov'è la borsa?" simply to an idiomatic matter.

Comment: I'd like to specify that _ci_ is mandatory in the answer _ce l'ho_ / _non ce l'ho_ (_l'ho_ / _non l'ho_ would sound very strange) and not in the question. _Hai l'ombrello?_ is a common usage.

Comment: @FabioF. Indeed, thanks. I've pointed that out in the answer.

Comment: Another way in which "ci/ce" appears, which I don't see above is in the meaning of non succeeding in accomplishing something. Esempio: "Io avevo cercato di farlo, però non ce l'ho fatto." And then [not] seeing something specific: "Pur troppo, non ci vedo." Is this also "Ci attualizzante?" I'm Barry, a white South African, who started learning this wonderful language 54 years ago... have loved it... and am still learning... I've still got one dream I hope to fulfil and that is to read "La Divina Commedia" in Dante's original text. I'll have to hurry, because in a week's time I shall be starting

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Barry! If you're trying to ask something, please use "Ask Question". This place is reserved for giving an answer to the question. If you are trying to comment a given answer, you will have to wait until you have enough reputation.

Answer (score -4):

Here ce means it.

A proper translation could be:

If it's not you who has the bag (it), then where is the bag.

A bad but literal translation could be:

If you don't have it, where is the bag?

Se tu non cel'hai

also means

If you are without a penis (ie. dickless), which also means, if you have no guts.

Since borsa is also the stock market, it could also mean

If you have no guts, then what the heck are you doing with your stock market skills.

Italian language can be quite flexible.

Comment: Not at all. "It" is represented by "l'", that is, "la". And the rest about the penis and so on is an invention of yours. Here "l(a)" clearly refers to the bag.

Comment: Sure, a bit of colloquial humor doesn't hurt.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the first part is factually wrong, while the rest is a hilarious, but potentially misleading sample of your fine humour?