Why are some verbs -cela and others -sela?
For instance, sentirsela and avercela, is there any way to make sense of the choice of pronouns used by the pronominal verbs?
For instance, let's take aversela and avercela. The wiktionary says aversela means: to pick on someone, while avercela means several things among which is: to be angry. How did these meanings come to be associated with those particular pronouns? Could the word avercela have been given the meaning, "to pick on someone", and aversela been given the meaning, "to get angry", just as well, and nothing about the Italian language would have any problem with the difference? That is, the choice of pronouns cannot, in any way, be understood to be related in any way to any of the meanings of the verbs, except as an arbitrary choice?

Related question:  https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11158/.

They are just different pronouns with different meanings. “Aversela” and “sentircela” are valid words too.

So the pronouns make no sense? They are just what they are, without rhyme or reason, arbitrarily chosen to allow the same verb to take on different meanings?

@Micheal: Not quite. A small part of it is arbitrary, as in English phrasal verbs, but not “without rhyme or reason”. Have you read the answer to the question linked by Charo?

Yes, I read it, but it did not appear to address my question, because it appeared to be about the meaning of specific pronominal verbs, not generally about the pronouns in pronominal verbs.

This is just a partial answer, to be possibly refined, to clarify things.
Much depends on the context: sentirsela and avercela (as well as other combinations of verbs and pronouns) may have more than one meaning. They mostly sound as normal composite forms, out of a verb and two pronouns, the ubiquitous and obscure-to-learners ce/ci (as in ci siamo?, ci penso io etc.) and normal la (= her or it).
For instance, avercela may simply mean “to have it”: “Hai la carta d'identità?” “Sì, ce l'ho” (about why this is more idiomatic than “Sì, la ho”, I assume there are other Q&A around here, or should be).
But avercela con qualcuno may also mean, as a pronominal verb, “to be cross with somebody” or the like.
Analogously, sentirsela is a composite of sentire (to feel, to hear) + si (in/for oneself) + la (her/it). For instance: “Perché pensi di avere la febbre? Hai usato il termometro?” “No, me la sento”, which would mean something like “I feel it in myself”.
So, everything “reduces” to understanding the multifaceted roles of ci, to understanding how normal verbs combine normally with pronouns, and to knowing the idiomatic meanings of pronominal verbs.
As to the meaning of specific pronominal verbs (aversela (a male), avercela (con qualcuno) and so on), I'm afraid that it cannot be deduced by their components and has to be learnt separately for each verb, a bit like for phrasal verbs in English (turn out, turn on, turn over, turn in...).

OP, if I misunderstood the question or gave too limited an answer, please let me know and I'll try to emend it.


Let me try to be more specific in order to clarify what I want to know. I will amend my question above.

Thanks, @Michael . I've added a sentence in my answer.

Thank you for the answer. I would point out, however, that the meanings for the phrasal verbs "turn out" and "turn in" could not be arbitrarily exchanged, because "out" and "in" confer specific, and opposite, senses to the meaning. As I understand from what you say, there is no similar relationship of the pronouns to the pronominal verbs in Italian.

I found this discussion quite relevant to my question: https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5950/9861

@Michael: I'm not sure about your comment about phrasal verbs: “turn out” means “prove to be the case”, “extinguish”, “produce” and other meanings that are quite removed from the basic senses of “to turn” and “out”, and the same holds for most phrasal verbs. As to “arbitrarily exchanged”, I'm not sure I understand. “Avercela” and “aversela” (and all other pronominal verbs) have each its distinct, specific meaning, as you have pointed out, and are not interchangeable as pronominal verb (in other uses the pronouns agree with the rest of the sentence etc.). Am I missing something?

Perhaps English is not your native language? While it is true, what say about the meaning of "turn out", a native speaker, even when dealing with those meanings of the phrasal verb, will take clues from the separate meaning of "out" that will enhance his/her understanding of the meaning in context. In that sense, "out" becomes integral to the understanding of the entire verb. Furthermore, "turn out" can also mean to make a physical turn, but out and not in. And certainly in that sense the "out" is cannot be arbitrarily interpreted.

It is helpful to my understanding to note that aversela and avercela differ by the fact that the "se" part declines when aversela is used, and the "ce" part does not when avercela is used. It seems to me that that fact must somehow be tied to the difference in meanings of the 2 verbs, but I do not see exactly how presently.

I also find this discussion very informative: https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5889/9861
